# Reset battery capacity in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, battery

I replaced the battery in my LG Gram and Windows 10 reported a 1% charge.  I ran it on battery only until it shut off, and then plugged in the laptop and let it charge overnight.  Now Windows is reporting the battery charge level at 10%, but not charging.

I assume that Windows is confused about the capacity of the new battery.  (The specification on the new battery is 80Wh, vs 72Wh for the previous battery which would not charge at all.)

Is there a way to reset it so that Windows thinks whatever it's seeing now is 100% charged, not 10% charged?

Or is there some setting that could prevent the system from charging the battery past 10%?

(As part of troubleshooting I have already uninstalled the "Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery" device and confirmed it has the lastest driver.)

Answer (score 1):

The battery may possibly be defective or not properly matched to your computer. Check both things.

To reset the battery (if it will reset), do the following:

Turn off the computer.
Plug it in and wait for full charge.
Disconnect the AC charger.
Turn on and use until the battery drops to 10% charge.
Then plug in and allow to charge fully.

If the battery will not charge to 100% then the battery is not correct for your computer or is defective.

If the battery appears good, then see if you have Battery Threshold management in your BIOS and Operating Software.  A good level for always plugged in is 80% (not 100%).