Why does laptop battery level suddenly drop from 35 percent to 7 percent?
I bought a used Dell Latitude 5400. I used it about 8 times. Out of those 8 times, I got this issue 3 times that my laptop battery suddenly dropped to 7 percent from 35 percent. I run battery test through BIOS, Dell power Manager and HWDmonitor and they show the battery health is excellent.
I think updates were installing in the background when this happened. I don't know if that would be the issue.
I don't know if that is normal or there is something wrong with the battery.

It might be that charging needs to be reset. See https://superuser.com/questions/1747666/reset-battery-capacity-in-windows-10, https://superuser.com/questions/1305783/battery-not-charging-laptop-only-works-when-plugged . Try that before replacing the battery -- and replace it if that fails to help.

This question is similar to: Reset battery capacity in Windows 10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
